# can not find videogular2 in angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, videogular2

I want to use the video player `videogular2` and I install this player with this commands:

`npm install videogular2`

`npm install @types/core-js`

```
VgCoreModule,
VgControlsModule,
VgOverlayPlayModule,
VgBufferingModule,
```

and I want to import module:

```
import { VgCoreModule } from 'videogular2/core';
import { VgControlsModule } from 'videogular2/controls';
import { VgOverlayPlayModule } from 'videogular2/overlay-play';
import { VgBufferingModule } from 'videogular2/buffering';
```

but it can not find this imports of this modules .

> Cannot find module 'videogular2/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
>
> Cannot find module 'videogular2/controls' or its corresponding type declarations.
>
> Cannot find module 'videogular2/overlay-play' or its corresponding type declarations.
>
> Cannot find module 'videogular2/buffering' or its corresponding type declarations.

**how can I solve this problem ????**

Answer (score 3):

seems like videogular2 does not support Angular 9+
https://github.com/videogular/videogular2/issues/904

The recommendation is to migrate to [ngx-videogular](https://github.com/videogular/ngx-videogular)